# Indirect reference to a button

Tags: c#, button, this

I'm having this code:

```
private void b9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    b9.Enabled = false;
    color = 8;
}
```

The problem is that i'm having a lot of buttons for disabling. Is there a chance i can use something like:

```
this.Enabled=false;
```

Comment: @Andics: Why don't you use sender?

Comment: I added an answer below that gives you differnt options. From just casting it to Button (when it is possible) to create a separate method that can be reusable for Buttons or any other type of control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably that is what you want

```
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( sender is Button )
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        button.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Use this routine for every button you need to disable on click.

Comment: you should use 'as', then check for null.. doing 'is' and then a direct cast is casting it twice

Answer (score 1):

It is known as single event handler for multiple controls. Just put following event handler for your buttons as many as you like.

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    button.IsEnable = false;

    // If you want to access text in the button
    ... = button.Content as object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button; // if sender is not a Button, btn will be null
    if (btn != null)
    {
        btn.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

If you want to apply the same behaviour to any clickable control, you can use Control class instead of Button. Button inherits from Control and the property Enabled is defined in Control class.

```
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = sender as Control; // if sender is not a Control, ctrl will be null
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        ctrl .Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to go one step further, you can create a method that disables the clicked control. Something like this:

```
private void DisableControl(object sender)
{
    Control ctrl = sender as Control;
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
         ctrl.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Then, you can call this method from the Click even handler like this:

```
private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisableControl(sender);
    }
```